# How would I find the centroid of Tesla body panel graphed on Desmos?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, algebraic-geometry, centroid

How can I find a centroid of a shape that is bound by certain known equations?
[Here is a picture of the Tesla body panel that I graphed in Desmos and of which I want to know the centroid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqQGn.png)

[image]

Comment: Assuming the material is a flat shape with uniform density?  Someone will have to confirm this, but I think if you find the horizontal and vertical lines dividing the figure into equal area halves, they will intersect at the centroid. That seems to boil this down to a manageable calc problem

Answer (score 0):

The half-area method mentioned in the comment does't find the centroid - see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594560/calculating-centre-of-area-using-a-method-i-found-but-it-gives-me-only-approxima) for reasons why.

The centroid $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ of a figure of constant density is found by picking an origin (it doesn't matter where), and calculating $\bar{x} = \dfrac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int x \cdot\text{height}(x)~dx$ and $\bar{y} = \dfrac{1}{A}\displaystyle\int y \cdot\text{width}(x)~dy$, where $A$ is the area of the figure breaking the areas of integration up as you need to work around the peculiarities of your boundary functions.